# Did Corey Booker never live in Newark where he was mayor?

Tags: united-states, politics

Trump just claimed in his latest rally (26/10/2020 - live at time of question posting) that Corey Booker "never lived in Newark" despite being the mayor there.

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: I don't think Trump making a random claim is a notable claim as I find it strange that he would win the office twice and not live in the city.

Comment: @JoeW: Our definition of notability is not that it is truthful, that it is from a reliable source (or whether you believe it!) It is that it is widely believed, and we generally accept that if someone famous said it publicly that it is likely widely believed.

Comment: The [tag:donald-trump] tag is for claims made *about* him, not claims made *by* him.  I'm removing it.

Comment: @NateEldredge fair enough.  What tag should I use?  Surely there should be a tag for claims made by him on a site like this?

Comment: We generally use tags to categorize what the claim itself is about.  From the point of view of scientific skepticism, the identity of the person making the claim is completely irrelevant to whether the claim itself is true or false, so it is not worth keeping track of.  Our only requirement is that it have been made by someone notable, so that we don't waste time on completely obscure claims that nobody really cares about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Corey Booker's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cory_Booker) links to a [2013 Buzzfeed Article](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/rubycramer/cory-booker-yes-i-live-in-newark) where he addresses those claims:

> The claim that Booker resides elsewhere, which his opponent alleged Monday, is a "desperate stunt," his campaign says. Property records and documentation of rental payments put Booker in Newark, where he has served as mayor since 2006.

Comment: While I agree this is rather stupid (or to use his words, a "desperate stunt"), the article notes the additional claims that the properties he owned/rented were either empty or used for other purposes. Ownership or rental does not necessarily demonstrate *residence*. Also noteworthy that this goes back to 2013.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Booker was Mayor of Newark from 2006 to 2013, so the Trump assertion is related to precisely that period

Comment: @Henry My point being that this isn't a *new* argument that Trump just put out there.